# Joomla modules do not show up when accessing the page from a link

Tags: joomla3.0

In Joomla I have the following situation:

I have an article (a page) that i declared in articles, the "products page". I did not enter any text or html in it.

I went to Module Manager and declared 3 modules (with text and html inside). The 3 modules are describing the 3 products that the company offers. Also I set the 3 modules to be placed in specific places (POSITIONS). I am using Gantry as a template, and the positions for the 3 modules are utility-a, utility-b and utility-c.

In each module, I chose the menu assignment, so that the modules will be shown in a specific page: the products page.

In MainMenu, I have a menu Item called "Products" that points to the empty article and is: index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2. Also in this menu item, I checked the Module Assignment, to see if the utility modules are shown and yes, they appear as "Display:yes"

NOW: When I access the "products page" from the main menu, the page shows up and contains the 3 utility modules, so everything is ok. But if I want to access this product page from a (manual)link (a href with the src above) inside a different page, then the product page shows up empty, like there is nothing on the page. I mean those utility modules do not show up. Only the empty article is shown.
How can I make the modules to show up?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I had to make a manual change to the link used as src. I had to add &Itemid=yyy at the end of the page link, and the yyy is the ID.
The useful documentation is here: http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_control_module_display_when_linking_to_an_article_with_no_menu_item

Thank you. Problem solved